# Why is Amazon using Text Fields instead of Radio Buttons for mutually exclusive options?

Tags: usability, accessibility, input-fields, radio-buttons, options

I have been trying to return an item on Amazon, and this window popped up asking me to fill in the bank details. Although they have used Radio Buttons in the first line for **Yes/No** question, **Account Type** options (Saving/Current) are shown in a text field kind of UI element.

[image]

If this is similar to [choice chips](https://material.io/components/chips) (Material Design), Why are they using a similar-looking text field for the account and IFSC code input?

Segmented controls and the choice chips work best when there are at least three options. Otherwise, it can be ambiguous.

Accessibility: Although a rare condition, people with monochromatic and partially monochromatic vision will have a hard time differentiating the selected vs non-selected option in the current design.

[image]

Comment: I think it's that they've build custom controls to replace Select elements as I've seen similar things when being asked to select which list to add something to, or which shipping option is preferred. It could be to facilitate styling or analytics or other things that are all speculation.

Comment: I would assume this is their drop-down component and they have the same form in use in multiple places (if I set up a business account for example there may be different options and more than 2/3). I don't think there is a "why" behind this other than a "why didn't they think about accessibility and design a component that looks like a `<select>`". Is there something a bit more detailed you want information on (regarding accessibility) as at the moment this is more of a observation of poor design. Are you wanting to know how they could differentiate for colour blind users etc?

Comment: @GrahamRitchie I'm just curious about this from a usability perspective.

Comment: without seeing teh code is hard to tell, but I'm pretty sure it's just a radio input disguised as text input or maybe a button (same as the chips you mention, only that for desktop). It's a bit weird, granted, but Amazon's usability always was... let's say... arguable.

Comment: As @Devin said it is hard from just an image to say how usable it is. Visually you have already made a good point that the drop-down (however it is structured) looks identical to an input if you are colour blind (Achromatopia - other colour blindness would probably be OK). Also for people with cognitive impairments it may be confusing that the control types look similar, they may not know what to expect when they click on the "account type" and start typing. I think that is about as much as we can comment on without **interacting** with it, as that is where most accessibility / UX issues lie!

Comment: The "savings/current" would not fail accessibility with respect to WCAG 1.4.1 "Use of Color) (https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#use-of-color) because in your screenshot, "savings" is also bold (compared to "current") so a monochromatic user *would* be able to tell the difference (albeit, it's not overly obvious).